# Apache Atlas: Http 503 Service Unavailable Error when connecting from Java Client

Tags: apache-atlas

I am running the atlas docker image from my MacOS . The admin dashboard works fine and I can create/ manage entities from the dashboard. But when I try to run the sample Java app provided with the Atlas source code, I get "Http 503 Service Unavailable Error" .

Following is the log

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.atlas.AtlasServiceException: Metadata service API org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2$API_V2@2f62ea70 failed with status 503 (Service Unavailable) Response Body (<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 503</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs/. Reason:
<pre> Service Unavailable</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty:// 8.1.19.v20160209</small></i>

</body>
</html>
)
at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:427)
at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:352)
at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.java:228)
at org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2.createAtlasTypeDefs(AtlasClientV2.java:323)
at org.apache.atlas.examples.sampleapp.TypeDefExample.batchCreateTypes(TypeDefExample.java:272)
at org.apache.atlas.examples.sampleapp.TypeDefExample.createTypeDefinitions(TypeDefExample.java:92)
at org.apache.atlas.examples.sampleapp.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.java:56)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58199', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Read the instructions on how to run the back-end server. That's why you see the "Service Unavailable" error.

Comment: I can create the entities and type defs via Rest API calls using postman. So I dont think there's any issue with the backend server, unless I am missing something